# Encryption with AsyncTask

Tags: android, encryption, android-asynctask

I use this code for encrypting Strings and it works perfectly:

```
public class Encryption {

    public String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);
    }

    public String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
    }

    private byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }

    private byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    private byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public String toHex(String txt) {
        return toHex(txt.getBytes());
    }

    public String fromHex(String hex) {
        return new String(toByte(hex));
    }

    public byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length() / 2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2),
                    16).byteValue();
        return result;
    }

    public String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)
            return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    private void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
    }

}
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to run this code in AsyncTask **and** display a ProgressDialog with the current process. It's no problem to run the code in an AsyncTask class, but I have no idea how I get the current progress.

**Edit:** I use this code for running the code in an AsyncTask:

```
private class EncryptData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pd.setMessage("Processing Data...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            Encryption encryptText = new Encryption();
            String result = "";

            try {
                result = encryptText.encrypt("123", arg0[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            pd.setProgress((int) (progress[0]));
            pd.setMessage("Processing Data... (" + progress[0] + "%)");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String ui) {
            setEncryptedData(ui);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

I want to use this code to encrypt a few MB of data.

**Edit:** I added this code to Ecryption:

```
    public int getProcess() {
        return ((int) (offset / totalSize) * 100);
    }

    public void setProgress(int totalSize, int offset) {
        this.totalSize = totalSize;
        this.offset = offset;
    }
```

Comment: Are you running this on a lot of data or something?

Comment: Yes, when I insert a few MB of data my application freezes for almost a minut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call doFinal(byte[]). This way you cannot get progress information from the Cipher. When you change to update (byte[], offset etc) you can chunk your data and show your progress in the loop. finish with do final btw.

you might end up with something like (from the head)

```
private byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    int offset = 0;
    byte[] encrypted;

    while(offset < clear.length()) {
        final byte[] answer = cipher.update(clear, offset, 1024);
        encrypted = Arrays.copyOf( encrypted, encrypted.length + 1024);
        System.arrayCopy(answer, 0, encrypted, offset, 1024);
        offset += 1024;
    }
    encrypted += cipher.doFinal(clear, offset, clear.length() - offset);
    return encrypted;
}
```

Comment: "The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) byte[], byte[]." I also added some code to my question

Comment: Sorry, i'm not working with java code in the moment, so I have to context switch... i adapted the code a bit, should be better now. Please use as example, not as production.

Comment: Using `update()` is the way to go, if you have a large file, etc. to encrypt. Otherwise just do it in one go. @ObAt your key derivation method is insecure and will break in 4.2, use a real key derivation function such as PBKDF2. Details: http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-password-based-encryption-on.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the [AsyncTask Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?  It is built-in.

> An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a
>   background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread. An
>   asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params,
>   Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground,
>   onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.

Comment: Yes I know, but how do I get data from the Cipher so I can cal onProgressUpdate?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. You do the heavily lifting in the threaded part and the ASyncTask has mechanisms to help you update controls using the UI thread

Comment: Thank you, do you have a source so I can try to fix the code?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. publishProgress and onProgressUpdate(Progress...) could work though

Answer (score 0):

Based on dmaij's answer, here's a more complete and working code for anyone looking at this in the future:

In Java:

```java
private byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    int offset = 0;
    int encoffset = 0;
    int incVal = 1024;
    byte[] encrypted;

    while(offset < clear.length) {
        if(offset + incVal > clear.length){
            final byte[] finalanswer = cipher.doFinal(clear, offset, clear.length - offset);
            encrypted = Arrays.copyOf(encrypted, encrypted.length + finalanswer.length);
            System.arraycopy(finalanswer, 0, encrypted, encoffset, finalanswer.length);
            // set progress from here
            break;
        }
        // set progress from here
        final byte[] answer = cipher.update(clear, offset, incVal);
        encrypted = Arrays.copyOf(encrypted, encrypted.length + answer.length);
        System.arraycopy(answer, 0, encrypted, encoffset, answer.length);
                                  
        offset += incVal;
        encoffset += answer.length;
    }

    return encrypted;
}
```

In Kotlin:

```kotlin
private fun encrypt(raw: ByteArray, clear: ByteArray): ByteArray{
    val skeySpec = SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec)
    
    val offset = 0
    val encoffset = 0
    val incVal = 1024
    var encrypted: ByteArray = byteArrayOf()
    
    while(offset < clear.size){
        if(offset + incVal > clear.size){
            val finalanswer = cipher.doFinal(clear, offset, clear.size - offset)
            encrypted = encrypted.copyOf(encrypted.size + finalanswer.size)
            System.arraycopy(finalanswer, 0, encrypted, encoffset, finalanswer.size)
            // set progress from here
            break;
        }
        // set progress from here
        val answer = cipher.update(clear, offset, incVal)
        encrypted = encrypted.copyOf(encrypted.size + answer.size)
        System.arraycopy(answer, 0, encrypted, encoffset, answer.size)
                               
        offset += incVal;
        encoffset += answer.size
    }
    
    return encrypted
}
```